# Python Number Guessing Game not Working

Tags: python

So I want to get into developing games and mods and such so I started researching programming languages and decided to choose python as my starting language because it seems fairly simple and very effective. I have been at it for about two days and using my current knowledge I tried to write the code for a guessing game! Before you read on, here is the code for my game:

```
import random

print("Welcome to a guessing game!")
print ("You have 3 try's to guess the correct number!")


number = raw_input ("Pick a number between 1 and 10!: " )
compnumber = random.randint (1,10)
enter = "Please press enter to exit..."
winner = "Congrats your a Winner!"
loser_high = "Uh-Oh!  That Number is to high!  Guess again!"
loser_low = "Uh-Oh!  That number is to low!  Guess again!"
demand = "Pick a number between 1 and 10!: "
game_over = "Sorry, you have lost the game!"


#Guess Number One
if number == compnumber :
    print (winner)
elif number != compnumber and number > compnumber :
    print (loser_high)
    guess2 = raw_input ()
elif number != compnumber and number < compnumber :
    print (loser_low)
    guess2 = raw_input (demand)

#Guess Number Two
if guess2 == compnumber :
    print (winner)
elif guess2 != compnumber and guess2 > compnumber :
    print (loser_high)
elif guess2 != compnumber and guess2 < compnumber :
    print (loser_low)
    guess3 = raw_input (demand)

#Guess Number Three
if guess3 == compnumber :
    print (winner)
elif guess3 != compnumber and guess3 > compnumber :
    print (loser_high)
elif guess3 != compnumber and guess3 < compnumber :
```

it's just a simple 40 lines of code that I am very proud of :D

So anyways here is my problem. When I run the application, I don't get any syntax error's or any error's in general but when I type in my first guess it ALWAYS says my guess is to high... and when I try again it says the same thing then the console closes... Why is this?

Also if anyone could give me some advice on how to simplify/compact my current code please post below and also if anyone has some tutorials for learning more advanced python things let me know! Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid using external resources, paste your code here instead.

Comment: You have not pasted your whole program.

Comment: BTW, it seems your code (even the original version on pastebin) is incomplete...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `raw_input()` returns a string, and `random.randint()` returns an integer. In Python 2, it is legal to compare objects of different types, and strings will always compare higher than integers.

You need to convert the user inputs to `int`s, then it should work.

```
guess = int(raw_input())
```

Also, you should not implement a loop by copy/pasting the more-or-less same code three times. Use a `for` or `while` loop:

```
for attempt in range(3):
    guess = int(raw_input(demand))
    if guess == compnumber:
        print winner
        break          # abort the loop
    elif guess > compnumber:
        print loser_high
    else:
        print loser_low
else:
    print game_over
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is that the raw input is a string, yet the random value is an integer. Try changing line 7 to:

```
number = int(raw_input("Pick a number between 1 and 10!: ").strip())
```

This modification does two things:

- Removes any whitespace around the input value (using `.strip()`)
- Converts the string into an integer type (using `int()`)

You will also need to do something similar on other lines where you take user input.

Comment: No need for `strip()`.

Comment: As far as I understand, `raw_input()` takes care of stripping the trailing newline, but an explicit `strip()` call will deal with any spaces that get inadvertently added around the number. Though I guess what should really happen is some more explicit input validation with a regex.

Comment: Why? Try `int("\n\t   123 \n \n\t")` - there is no need to strip whitespace at all.

Comment: I went by what the [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) docs say. Which, of course, isn't as reliable as testing the thing :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the string that `raw_input` returns to a number. You can also have a single loop for the whole game and prevent code repetition. One other thing is, after checking `number == compnumber` in the `if` condition, you don't have to check for `number != compnumber` in the else part:

```
# ....

for i in range(3):
    number = int(raw_input ("Pick a number between 1 and 10!: " ))
    if number == compnumber :
        print (winner)
        exit(0)
    elif number > compnumber :
        print (loser_high)
    elif number < compnumber :
        print (loser_low)
    print "Guess again!"
```

Comment: I don't think you need to check all those conditions :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

LOSER_HIGH, LOSER_LOW, WINNER = 1, -1, 0
GUESS_TIMES = 3

WIN_STR = "Congrats your a Winner!"
GAMEOVER_STR = "Sorry, you have lost the game!"
LOSER_HIGH_STR = "Uh-Oh!  That Number is to high!  Guess again!"
LOSER_LOW_STR = "Uh-Oh!  That number is to low!  Guess again!"
DEMAND_STR = "Pick a number between 1 and 10!: "


def do_guess(number, compnumber):
    if number > compnumber:
        return LOSER_HIGH
    elif number < compnumber:
        return LOSER_LOW
    else:
        return WINNER

def main():
    compnumber = random.randint (1,10)

    print ("Welcome to a guessing game!")
    print ("You have 3 try's to guess the correct number!") 

    for i in xrange(GUESS_TIMES):
        number = int(raw_input(DEMAND_STR))
        ret = do_guess(number, compnumber)
        if ret == LOSER_HIGH:
            print LOSER_HIGH_STR
        elif ret == LOSER_LOW:
            print LOSER_LOW_STR
        else:
            print WIN_STR
            break
    else:
        print GAMEOVER_STR

    raw_input("Please press enter to exit...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It would probably help the OP if you highlight and explain the key changes you have made.